# Capitalize home directories and append string

Tags: samba, samba4

In the `[homes]` section of my `smba.conf` file, `%S` is a variable holding `the name of the current service`. If `%S` is `username`, the folder `/mnt/data/%S` is displayed to user `username` as "username". Is it possible to display the folder `/mnt/data/%S` to the user with a capitalized `username` and another string e.g. "Username - Personal storage"?